# Chrome extension occasionally crashing - why?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, indexeddb

I am developing an extension which uses the tab API, long-lived connections and HTML5 indexedDB. The extension crashes randomly (or at least I cannot reproduce a crash scenario). I took a look the the chrome log:

```
[22654:-1322192896:0118/184514:VERBOSE1:ipc_sync_channel.cc(382)] Canceling pending sends
[22649:-1398687192:0118/184514:VERBOSE1:speech_input_extension_manager.cc(228)] Extension unloaded. Requesting to enforce stop...
[22654:-1398687192:0118/184514:VERBOSE1:ipc_sync_channel.cc(382)] Canceling pending sends
[22654:-1322192896:0118/184514:VERBOSE1:ipc_sync_channel.cc(382)] Canceling pending sends
[22808:-1398687192:0118/184514:VERBOSE1:chrome_v8_context.cc(125)] Could not execute chrome hidden method: Port.dispatchOnDisconnect
[22808:-1398687192:0118/184514:VERBOSE1:chrome_v8_context.cc(125)] Could not execute chrome hidden method: Port.dispatchOnDisconnect
[22808:-1398687192:0118/184514:VERBOSE1:chrome_v8_context.cc(125)] Could not execute chrome hidden method: Port.dispatchOnDisconnect
[22808:-1398687192:0118/184514:VERBOSE1:chrome_v8_context.cc(125)] Could not execute chrome hidden method: Port.dispatchOnDisconnect
[22808:-1398687192:0118/184514:VERBOSE1:chrome_v8_context.cc(125)] Could not execute chrome hidden method: Port.dispatchOnDisconnect
[22808:-1398687192:0118/184514:VERBOSE1:chrome_v8_context.cc(125)] Could not execute chrome hidden method: Port.dispatchOnDisconnect
[22649:-1398687192:0118/184514:VERBOSE1:notification_ui_manager_impl.cc(83)] Added notification. URL: data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0A%3Chtml%3E%0A%3Chead%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctitle%3E%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%3Cstyle%3E%0A%20%20body%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20direction%3A%20ltr%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%23icon%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20height%3A%2032px%3B%0A%20%20%20%20width%3A%2032px%3B%0A%20%20%20%20float%3A%20left%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%23title%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20margin-left%3A%2038px%3B%0A%20%20%20%20font-weight%3A%20bold%3B%0A%20%20%20%20font-size%3A%2013px%3B%0A%20%20%20%20font-family%3A%20helvetica%2C%20arial%2C%20sans-serif%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%23description%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20margin-left%3A%2038px%3B%0A%20%20%20%20font-family%3A%20helvetica%2C%20arial%2C%20sans-serif%3B%0A%20%20%20%20font-size%3A%2013px%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%0A%3C%2Fhead%3E%0A%3Cbody%3E%0A%20%20%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22icon%22%3E%3Cimg%20src%3D%22chrome-extension%3A%2F%2Fegoecnhkgdfeofmdmjgopmdjbaknldjf%2Fres%2Ficon_48x48.png%22%20width%3D%2232%22%20height%3D%2232%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22title%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22description%22%3EHelloWorld%20ist%20abgest%C3%BCrzt.%20Klicken%20Sie%20auf%20dieses%20Fenster%2C%20um%20die%20Erweiterung%20erneut%20zu%20laden.%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3C%2Fbody%3E%0A%3C%2Fhtml%3E%0A
```

I activated the most chatty verbose mode but it doesn't make sense to me what causes the crash. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the crash show up in chrome://crashes/

Comment: No, it doesn't. Only a notification appears which says that the extension has crashed.

Answer (score 0):

You should submit a ticket to the Chromium Project http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list and someone from Google will respond back to you in couple days.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem it took me a full day to solve, I think it may apply. My popup extension would run without crashing if I simply opened it, however if I opened the extension in developer mode (ie right click -> 'Inspect Popup') the next time I'd try to open it would crash.

This appears to be a problem with Chrome's new Device Mode feature. To fix this, I had to open my popup.html file in a new tab, and make sure Device Mode was OFF. Then, when I opened my extension in developer mode, it would not crash anymore.

To turn off Device Mode:

- Open your html file in a new tab
- Enter developer mode (View -> Developer -> Javascript Console)
- Ensure that device mode is off (Device mode is toggled by clicking the small image of a mobile phone that is beside the magnifying glass)

Hope this helps one of you.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your bug. Which Chrome version, operating system and extension are you using to trigger a crash?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't seem to reproduce the bug either. I've done a major redesign of the styling, perhaps it was a setting in the CSS. Hopefully this helps someone on the off chance they have the same problem.

Comment: If you have version control, then you could check out a previous version and try to reproduce the bug. If you use git, try `git bisect` to quickly locate the code responsible for the crash.